# Not able to set/override docker entrypoint to execute two commands

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to set/override the docker entrypoint when I am launching my docker image but I am getting an unexpected behavior

***Scenario 1 (Not working)***

1. **Docker Run Command** --> docker run --rm -it --privileged --net=host
    python3.6 -m CameraServerBasler.pylon_video &
   python3.6 -m CameraServerBasler.server
2. **Output** --> /usr/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module
   specification for 'CameraServerBasler.server' (ModuleNotFoundError:
   No module named 'CameraServerBasler')

***Scenario 2 (Working)***

If I execute the same command inside the docker image bash everything is working as expected

1. **Docker Run Command** --> docker run --rm -it --privileged --net=host --entrypoint=/bin/bash
2. **Command executed inside the docker image** --> python3.6 -m
   CameraServerBasler.server & python3.6 -m
   CameraServerBasler.pylon_video
3. **Output** --> both servers(modules) up and running as expected (server
   and pylon_video)

Docker image --> ubuntu:18.04

Am I missing something in the docker run command?

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be in the same Docker container?  If you're running the container `--privileged --net host`, is there any benefit to them being in Docker at all?

Comment: share dockerfile, please and format commands as code

Comment: did you mean `&&` in your command ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this issue using a sh script, but still not very clear why is not working using the Approach #1

**Approach #1 Not Working**

Entry point declared in the docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.6", "-m", "CameraServerBasler.server", "&", "python3.6", "-m", "CameraServerBasler.pylon_video"]
```

**Approach #2 Working**

Entry point declared in the docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "init.sh"]
```

**init.sh File Content**

```
python3.6 -m CameraServerBasler.server & python3.6 -m CameraServerBasler.pylon_video
```